# Kivy, Systematic Animation using Clock.interval Error

Tags: python, kivy

Ive been working on this code for some time now for a tetris app which makes blocks fall systematically one after the other and do not overlap each other.I have come up with this code but keep getting this an error saying that my widget class already has a parent. Some help please

```
#Block 1 - 5 are stated above
class Block6(Widget):
    vel_x = NumericProperty(0)
    vel_y = NumericProperty(-5)
    position = ReferenceListProperty(vel_x,vel_y)
    def fall(self, pos):
        self.pos =  Vector(self.position) + self.pos
        if self.pos[1]==0:
            self.position[1] = 0

class TetrisApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = TetrisGame()
        x = Window.width
        block1 = Block1(pos=(randint(0,x),Window.height))
        block2 = Block2(pos=(randint(0,x),Window.height))
        block3 = Block3(pos=(randint(0,x),Window.height))
        block4 = Block4(pos=(randint(0,x),Window.height))
        block5 = Block5(pos=(randint(0,x),Window.height))
        block6 = Block6(pos=(randint(0,x),Window.height))
        allblocks = (block1, block2, block3, block4, block5, block6)
        while game:
            blockchoice = randint(1,6)
            if blockchoice == 1:
                game.add_widget(block1)
                Clock.schedule_interval(block1.fall,1/60)
                for i in allblocks:
                    if block1.collide_widget(i):
                        block1.position[1] = 0
            elif blockchoice == 2:
                game.add_widget(block2)
                Clock.schedule_interval(block2.fall,1/60)
                    for i in allblocks:
                    if block2.collide_widget(i):
                        block2.position[1] = 0
            elif blockchoice == 3:
                game.add_widget(block3)
                Clock.schedule_interval(block3.fall,1/60)
                for i in allblocks:
                    if block3.collide_widget(i):
                        block3.position[1] = 0
            elif blockchoice == 4:
                game.add_widget(block4)
                Clock.schedule_interval(block4.fall,1/60)
                for i in allblocks:
                    if block4.collide_widget(i):
                        block4.position[1] = 0
            elif blockchoice == 5:
                game.add_widget(block5)
                Clock.schedule_interval(block5.fall,1/60)
                for i in allblocks:
                    if block5.collide_widget(i):
                        block5.position[1] = 0
            elif blockchoice == 6:
                game.add_widget(block6)
                Clock.schedule_interval(block6.fall,1/60)
                for i in allblocks:
                    if block6.collide_widget(i):
                        block6.position[1] = 0
            else:  
                print('this is not possible')
        return game

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TetrisApp().run()
```

Ive written my kv file and everything but keep getting this error
[image: This is the error i keep getting]

I would really appreciate any help on where the error is coming from

Answer (score 0):

## Tetris Game

There are seven tetrominos. At any one time, there is only one falling tetromino. Please refer to the suggestion/snippet.

### Snippet

```
class TetrisApp(App):

    def build(self):
        game = TetrisGame()
        x = Window.width
        allblocks = []

        while game:
            blockchoice = randint(1,6)
            if blockchoice == 1:
                block = Block1(pos=(randint(0, x), Window.height))
            elif blockchoice == 2:
                block = Block2(pos=(randint(0, x), Window.height))
            elif blockchoice == 3:
                block = Block3(pos=(randint(0, x), Window.height))
            elif blockchoice == 4:
                block = Block4(pos=(randint(0, x), Window.height))
            elif blockchoice == 5:
                block = Block5(pos=(randint(0, x), Window.height))
            elif blockchoice == 6:
                block = Block6(pos=(randint(0, x), Window.height))
            elif blockchoice == 7:
                block = Block7(pos=(randint(0, x), Window.height))

            game.add_widget(block)

            Clock.schedule_interval(block.fall,1/60)

            for i in allblocks:
                if block.collide_widget(i):
                    block.position[1] = 0
            else:
                print('this is not possible')
        return game
```

## Solution - WidgetException: cannot add ... it already has a parent

Before adding each block, you need to check whether each block existed.

### Snippet

```
if block1 in game.children:
    # block1 existed
    block1.y = Window.height    # reset y i.e. start from top again
else:
    # block does not exist
    game.add_widget(block1)
```

Comment: If I do this I will have a constant of 6 blocks in my app and I want the blocks to keep generating and falling infinitely. How can I do this

Comment: Please refer to updated post containing a suggestion.